# PDF417 Barcode recognition in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, force.com

I have a requirement where I need to recognise a driver license barcode([PDF417](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF417)) in Visualforce with Apex or JavaScript. I googled but didn't find any solution. Does someone has experience with such things and can give me a right direction or advice?

I know that the question contains too bit details but it's really all what I have. Any ideas would be great. Thanks.

Comment: How are you attempting to read/capture the barcode?

Comment: @Eric it's actually the question. How to read this data. I was looking for library\existing approach which can do that. I found a many barcode scanning libs in github and over the Internet. But these approaches can't handle PDF417 or does not fit Salesforce environment.

Comment: Use a handheld barcode scanner. It's software will read it and put the info where u need it

Comment: I did an implementation where the scanner was placed in keyboard mode, and you'd just scan into the page via keypress events. Have you tried that?